# Error with begin{Proof}...\end{Proof} command

Tags: theorems

I have written the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}  
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{lemma}   
My lemma  
\end{lemma}   

\begin{Proof}  
My proof  
\end{Proof}  

\end{document}
```

It shows the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment Proof undefined.  
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.  
Type H <return> for immediate help.  
...  
l.15 \begin{Proof}  
Your command was ignored.  
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,  
or <return> to continue without it.  
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{Proof}.  
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.  
Type H <return> for immediate help.  
...  
l.17 \end{Proof}  
Your command was ignored.  
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,  
or <return> to continue without it.
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome! It should be `\begin{proof}` and `\end{proof}`. LaTeX commands are case sensitive.

Comment: Case sensitive was the problem Proof should be proof. Please try with **\begin{proof}My Proof\end{proof}**

Answer (score 3):

Case sensitivity is the problem: `Proof` should be `proof`. Please try with

```
\begin{proof}
My Proof
\end{proof}
```